# Journey Builder 'Salesforce Data' Entry Event UPDATE is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm having a problem with my marketing cloud org. In **Journey Builder**, I'm using '**Salesforce data**', and I'm filtering based on whether data is **created** or **updated**. I'm also checking for non-empty custom fields and email addresses. In the '**Decision Split**', I am defining paths based on the formula field. Everything works well at the creation of new records, but it's **not working on updation**. Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused by many things, but I see that you're using a formula field. You should know that formula fields contained in Synchronized Data Sources update only when an update for another field on the object occurs.

Check out this article by SF:

> The field type of Sales Cloud fields included in the 'Criteria' can
> impact if the injection will be successful. Formula field types will not
> trigger based on an 'Update'. Since formula types are dependent on
> other fields, they are unable to satisfy the state change of 'not
> qualifying', to 'qualifying'. This state change is required in order
> to qualify as an 'Update' action. Formula field types will trigger
> injection when 'Create' is the action used.

**Sources:**

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382915&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5